# seting ODBC Datasource in IBM AIX server

Tags: odbc, aix, messagebroker

I have develop IBM Message broker flow database application in windows xp environment. the database accessed using ODBC datasource. basically, I use compute node with esql programming to select query in database, and I set the datasource in the compute node properties.

Now want to deployed my project to AIX server. but, I dont know how to set ODBC datasource in AIX server.

can you help me to how to set odbc in AIX server, can you help me to solve my problem ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini file which has the information about your data source in it, then setup environment variables (LD_LIBRARY_PATH, ODBCINI) to point towards your ini files, driver and driver manager binary files.